# Walker2d AI Gym doesn't seem to learn

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I have been trying to get a basic actor critic agent learning in the MuJoCO Walker2D environment. After many many variations in models, losses, hyperparamters I seem to be making no progress (the agent fails to have any noticeable difference over 250k steps.

I realised I probably have many many errors/ issues, but I really am completely stuck as to what to try next.

My most recent agent is as follows:

```
  def __init__(
      self,
      num_actions: int):
    """Initialize."""
    super().__init__()
    self.common = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu",  kernel_initializer='random_normal')  
    self.common4 = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu",  kernel_initializer='random_normal')
    self.actor_means = layers.Dense(num_actions, activation="tanh",  kernel_initializer='random_normal')
    self.critic = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear") #1 node to give a value estimate of the policy
    #next lines are for indipendant second critic
    self.crit_dense1 = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu",  kernel_initializer='random_normal')
    self.crit2 = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear",  kernel_initializer='random_normal')

  def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
    a = tf.expand_dims(inputs, 0)
    b = self.common(a)
    d = self.common4(b)
    means = self.actor_means(d)
    q2 = self.crit_dense1(a)
    q2 = self.crit2(q2)
    return means, q2
```

The episode is:

```
  for t in tf.range(max_steps):
    # Run the model and to get action probabilities and critic value
    action_dist_t, value = model(state)
    values = values.write(t, value)
    dist = tfd.Normal(loc=action_dist_t, scale=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])
    action=dist.sample([1])[0]

    action = tf.clip_by_value(action, -0.99, 0.99)
    action_probs = action_probs.write(t, dist.prob(action_dist_t))#- action
    actions = actions.write(t, action)
    # Apply action to the environment to get next state and reward

    state, reward, done= env_step(tf.cast(tf.squeeze(action), tf.float32)) #
    #tf.print(str(reward))
    state.set_shape(initial_state_shape)
    # Store reward
    rewards = rewards.write(t, reward)

    if tf.cast(done, tf.bool):
      break
```

The loss is:

```
def compute_loss(
    action_probs: tf.Tensor,
    values: tf.Tensor,
    returns: tf.Tensor,
    actions: tf.Tensor
  ) -> tf.Tensor: #
  """Computes the combined Actor-Critic loss."""

  advantage = (returns - values)  #+ 0.01
  actor_loss = -tf.math.reduce_sum(advantage*action_probs, axis=-1)  #tf.math.abs

  critic_loss = huber_loss(values, returns)


  return actor_loss + critic_loss
```

and training step:

```
def train_step(
    initial_state: tf.Tensor,
    model: tf.keras.Model,
    optimizer: tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer,
    gamma: float,
    max_steps_per_episode: int) -> tf.Tensor:
  """Runs a model training step."""

  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

    # Run the model for one episode to collect training data
    action_probs, values, rewards, actions = run_episode(
        initial_state, model, max_steps_per_episode)

    # Calculate the expected returns
    returns = get_expected_return(rewards, gamma)

    # Convert training data to appropriate TF tensor shapes
    action_probs, values, returns, actions = [
        tf.expand_dims(x, 1) for x in [action_probs, values, returns, actions]]

    # Calculate the loss values to update our network
    loss = compute_loss(action_probs, values, returns, actions)

  grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  grads = [tf.clip_by_value(grad, -0.5, 0.5) for grad in grads]
  #grads,_  = tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads, -3)
  # Compute the gradients from the loss

  #for var, grad in zip(model.trainable_variables, grads):
   # print(f"Variable: {var.name}, Gradient Norm: {tf.norm(grad)}")
  # Apply the gradients to the model's parameters
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

  episode_reward = tf.math.reduce_sum(rewards)
  critic_estimate = tf.math.reduce_sum(values)
```

I have tried alternative losses (NLL, custom losseses suggested by CoPilot). I have tried different model architectures (more layers, wider layers, distributions on outputs) and a range of hyperparamters (gamma range(0.25-0.99), learning rate(0.1,0.01,0.001). I have also tried with and without gradiant clipping, with sum rather than mean reduce. Max reward remains <5.